# Why do almost all Java jobs (postings and from recruiters) say J2EE rather than the newer JEE versions?

Tags: java, java-ee

I'm still fairly new to Java but have definite comfort now working within the framework I am used to which would mainly be focused on Spring, Hibernate and JEE 6. It seems like every time I talk to a recruiter all they do is throw around the keyword "J2EE", they need someone with J2EE experience, etc. I am aware that legacy systems would still be using J2EE but it seems like at least some jobs would be advertising JEE now. Just curious if they are just stuck with some keyword that they can't seem to wrap their heads around it having a newer version or what. Having not done Java all that long, I haven't used J2EE specifically but wouldn't it be fairly easy to adapt having used the newer enterprise edition?

Just curious to hear anything about this from someone with more experience.

Comment: If you're worried about recruiters not understanding things like "JEE 6", "JavaEE", etc... put "I have experience with Java (JavaEE/J2EE)" so it will trip their buzzword detector.

Comment: Java is Java, only thing different is the additional class libraries. Annoying.

Comment: "JxEEy" is deprecated. Use "Java EE x" but it rolls off the tongue like a sea urchin.

Comment: J2EE originally stood for "Java 2" Enterprise Edition. We are long past Java 2. In J2EE versions 3 and 4, Sun kept it for branding reasons. In version 5, they finally accepted the 2 wasn't meaningful and got rid of it.

Answer (score 9):

Most corporations don't live on the bleeding edge so they still use JEE.  However, most recruiters just copy paste from their buzz word dictionary.  Additionally I still see J2SE when in reality its JSE.

Answer (score 5):

Just because Sun Marketing could not figure out what it was to be called and hence changed it several times, it does not mean that the rest of the world can keep up.

Also it is "Java EE 6" these days.

Answer (score 5):

I use J2EE, errr, sorry, actually Java EE 6 and I can't stop calling it J2EE...  Same thing as when they rename ballparks and malls, yet people still keep using the old name.  Don't take "J2EE" too literally, they could be using the latest & greatest...

Comment: Seven years later and still hearing J2EE. And now that it's with the Eclipse Foundation, it has to be renamed again because Oracle owns the Java trademark.

Answer (score 3):

"J2EE", "Java EE", "JEE", even Sun/Oracle cannot agree on the name, so how can recruiters be expected to use the right one?

It's a safe bet that you have to claim you know Java EE, since that is usually what recruiters are looking for, not plain Java. And since you are familiar with Spring, Hibernate, etc, you already know a subset of Java EE.